# Can't write a concise for loop in Dart

Tags: for-loop, dart

In some other languages one can write a for loop like this:

```dart
for (var item in 0..100) {
  print(item);
}
```

Why is it not possible in Dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the obvious classical way:

```
for (var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    print(i);
}
```

there's [`Iterable.generate()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Iterable/Iterable.generate.html):

```
for (var i in Iterable.generate(100)) {
    print(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [range](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.iterables/range.html) defined in the quiver library

> ```
> Iterable<num> range (
>     num startOrStop,
>     [num stop,
>     num step]
> )
> ```

```
import 'package:quiver/iterables.dart';

for (var i in range(100)) {
    print(i);
}
```